# Can you explain the "isXxx" method names in Java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

Is there in one of the specifications any reference to methods that start with "is", while the suffix of the method's name is a property's name (similar to getter/setter methods of Java beans)?

For example:

```
public boolean isConditionTrue() {
   ...
   ...
}

private boolean conditionTrue;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is a form of getter method. See a reference down the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is only valid for primitive boolean. Here is an excerpt from [the spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html):

> 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>         In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>             public boolean is();
>         This “is” method may be provided instead of a “get” meth-
>         od, or it may be provided in addition to a “get” method.
>         In either case, if the “is” method is present for a boolean property then we will
>         use the “is” method to read the property value.
>         An example boolean property might be:
>                      public boolean isMarsupial();
>                      public void setMarsupial(boolean m);

Be aware of using `isXxx() : Boolean` functions if you are going to use them in conjunction with things like JSTL tags (using `${object.xxx}` syntax). They won't pick it up and you have to modify it to `getXxx() : Boolean`.

Comment: quote block might be better here

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the following in a Spring bean: `@AssertTrue public boolean isConditionTrue() { return false; }`, JSP has: `<form:errors path="conditionTrue" cssClass="error" />` However I see no "error" message, could you explain why? (other properties of that bean do show error messages)

Comment: I don't know the answer for this one, but I think you should address fileds in the form using 'path' attribute (you can also use a wildcard). I am not sure if you can access a method here.

Comment: Thanks! I do have the field (property) as well: `private boolean conditionTrue;` but as I said I get no error message. Anyway, I've just started a new question for this.

Comment: I meant something like a text box by 'field' ;-)

Comment: Gotcha, but I am not sure what you meant by me accessing a method? I was accessing the conditionTrue property like any other property in the command object. I thought once the getter returns false, some message is being created.

Answer (score 24):

This is a Java naming convention,

> If the method returns a `boolean` value, use `is` or `has` as the prefix for
>   the method name. For example, use `isOverdrawn` or `hasCreditLeft` for
>   methods that return `true` or `false` values. Avoid the use of the word
>   `not` in the `boolean` method name, use the `!` operator instead. For
>   example, use `!isOverdrawn` instead of `isNotOverdrawn`.

See also:

- [Java Style Guide: Method Naming Convention](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html)
- [Java Language Specification - Method Names](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.8.4)

---

According to the Java Language Specification,

> A method that tests a `boolean` condition `V` about an object should be
>   named `isV`. An example is the method `isInterrupted` of class `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question! Please see my follow-up to member "houman001".

Comment: @rapt, I suggest you make that a separate question. It really has no relevance here.

Answer (score 6):

The is `is` a prefix for accessor methods to `boolean` type instance variables.

This is the convention for `boolean` data types, while `get/set` is the `convention` for other types.

Comment: I think `is` should be used almost in every function, which returns boolean, not only accessors.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question! Please see my follow-up to member "houman001".