# Java Applet SecurityException Prohibited package name: java

Tags: java, json, xml, applet, securityexception

I'm very new to Java and i want to create a Java Applet.
My .jar File is signed and the Package with .class ... is in the folder java
(--> java.lal.class).
But I got only this error:

SecurityException

Prhibited package name: java

Java Code:

```
package lal;
import java.applet.Applet;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class lal extends Applet {

/**
 * @param args 
 * @throws JSONException
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String jsonStr = "SOME JSON DATA :) ";
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    System.out.println(XML.toString(jsonObj));
  }

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<applet code="java.lal.class" width="700" height="750">
</applet>
```

Comment: ..have you considered renaming your package to something other than *java*?

Comment: But my package is named "lal" or is the folder "java" the package? Sorry I#m very new to Java :D

Comment: Yes. look in your code: `code="java.lal.class"`

Comment: wow :D perfect Thank you! I got a new Error but I try to solve it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since the code starts:

```
package lal;
import java.applet.Applet;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class lal extends Applet { 
    // ...
```

That means the fully qualified class name is `lal.lal` where the first part is the package, and the second is the class name.

The `code` attribute of the `applet` HTML element should therefore be:

```
<applet code="lal.lal" width="700" height="750">
</applet>
```

Comment: @Doc_Schobs: Using [conventional names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7155491/230513) can help  make this easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Just like your error says, you're not allowed to use `java` in your package name for security reasons.

Just rename your package to something that doesn't contain reserved literals like `java`.

Comment: Thank you! :)  I got a new Error but I try to solve it ;)